# ARM: Solution Template: Multiple VMs: how to configure content of BackendAddresses array without hard coding ips

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-rm-template

I tried to RTFM in [the usual place](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates), but none of the examples in `101-application-gateway` exhibited this pattern.  I have a Solution Template ARM template that deploys N VMs.  I need to cause an Azure Application Gateway to be provisioned and configured with `BackendAddresses` that refer to those N VMs.  I am familiar with the `copy` and `copyIndex()` pattern, but I don't see how to apply it here.  The examples have code like:

```
"backendAddressPools": [
    {
        "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
        "properties": {
            "BackendAddresses": [
                {
                    "IpAddress": "[parameters('backendIpAddress1')]"
                },
                {
                    "IpAddress": "[parameters('backendIpAddress2')]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

but I would like to do something like:

```
"backendAddressPools": [
    {
        "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
        "properties": {
            "BackendAddresses": [
                {
                    "IpAddress": "[concat(variables('managedVMPrefix'), copyIndex(),variables('nicName'))]"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
],
```

I'm sure that won't work because I need N entries in the `BackendAddressess` array.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at [the reference docs for the copy facility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-multiple-instances), I realized this is the correct syntax:

```
"backendAddressPools": [
  {
    "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
    "properties": {
        "copy": [{
      "name": "BackendAddresses",
      "count": "[parameters('numberOfInstances')]",
      "input": {
        "IpAddress": "[reference(concat(variables('managedVMPrefix'), copyIndex('BackendAddresses', 1), variables('publicIPAddressName'))).properties.ipAddress]"
      }
        }]
    }
  }
]
```

Given `NumberOfInstances` is 3 and `reference(concat(variables('managedVMPrefix'), copyIndex('BackendAddresses'), variables('nicName')))` resolves to `mspVM1publicIp`, `mspVM2publicIp`, `mspVM1publicIp`, which itself is passed through the `reference()` function to yield `10.0.1.10`, `10.0.1.11`, `10.0.1.12`, this produces the following output:

```
"backendAddressPools": [
  {
    "name": "appGatewayBackendPool",
    "properties": {
      "BackendAddresses": [
        {
          "IpAddress": "[10.0.1.10]"
        },
        {
          "IpAddress": "[10.0.1.11]"
        },
        {
          "IpAddress": "[10.0.1.12]"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I must say I think the ARM template syntax is terribly difficult to work with, understand, and maintain, but maybe it gets easier with more experience.